# C++ "Access violation reading location" Error

Tags: c++

I have the following `Vertex` struct in a `Graph` class:

```
struct Vertex
{
    string country;
    string city;
    double lon;
    double lat;
    vector<edge> *adj;

    Vertex(string country, string city, double lon, double lat)
    {
        this->country = country;
        this->city = city;
        this->lon = lon;
        this->lat = lat;
        this->adj = new vector<edge>();
    }
};
```

When calling the method I've written called `getCost()`, I keep getting the same Unhandled Exception

> Access violation reading location 0x00000048

and I cannot figure out why.

the `getCost()` method:

```
void Graph::getCost(string from, string to)
{

    Vertex *f = (findvertex(from));
    vector<edge> *v = f->adj;     // Here is where it gives the error
    vector<edge>::iterator itr = v->begin();

    for (; itr != v->end(); itr++)
    {
        if (((*itr).dest)->city == to)
            cout << "\nCost:-" << (*itr).cost;
    }
}
```

The method `findvertex()` returns a value of type `Vertex*`. Why do I keep receiving this error?

the findVertex method:

```
Vertex* Graph::findvertex(string s)
{
    vmap::iterator itr = map1.begin();
    while (itr != map1.end())
    {
        if (itr->first == s){

            return itr->second;
        }
        itr++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Where `map1` is defined:

```
typedef map< string, Vertex *, less<string> > vmap;
vmap map1;
```

Comment: You have posted everything beside the most relevant part. Hint: findvertex

Comment: Can you post findVertex please?

Comment: What is findvertex? i.e. if it doesn't return a concrete Vertex object, then that's your error.

Comment: I have posted the findvertex method my mistake

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You haven't posted the `findvertex` method, but Access Reading Violation with an offset like `0x00000048` means that the `Vertex* f;` in your getCost function is receiving null, and when trying to access the member `adj` in the `null` Vertex pointer (that is, in `f`), it is offsetting to `adj` (in this case,  72 bytes ( 0x48 bytes in decimal )), it's reading near the `0` or `null` memory address.

Doing a read like this violates Operating-System protected memory, and more importantly means whatever you're pointing at isn't a valid pointer. Make sure `findvertex` isn't returning null, or do a comparisong for null on `f` before using it to keep yourself sane (or use an assert):

`assert( f != null ); // A good sanity check`

**EDIT:**

If you have a `map` for doing something like a find, you can just use the map's [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) method to make sure the vertex exists:

```
Vertex* Graph::findvertex(string s)
{
    vmap::iterator itr = map1.find( s );
    if ( itr == map1.end() )
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return itr->second;
}
```

Just make sure you're still careful to handle the error case where it does return `NULL`. Otherwise, you'll keep getting this access violation.

Comment: I have replaced the findvertex method accordingly, however, the error is still the same

Comment: @AlexAlex That means that even though it's finding something, you may have two potential issues. One is that you're actually inserting null into the map for that specific String key. The other is that the vertex actually isn't in the map in the first place. A debugger breakpoint (for IDEs) or doing a print of the key/value and doing a print when you add values to the map, to make sure you're not adding null, would be advisable.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I went and created a view method to print out all of the vertices in the map. They all printed along with their attributes I did not see any null values

Comment: @AlexAlex That's good, then. Hopefully the search picks them up. I hope you were able to solve the problem!

Answer (score 3):

```
Vertex *f=(findvertex(from));
if(!f) {
    cerr << "vertex not found" << endl;
    exit(1) // or return;
}
```

Because `findVertex` can return `NULL` if it can't find the vertex.

Otherwise this `f->adj;` is trying to do

```
NULL->adj;
```

Which causes access violation.

Comment: that does catch the error thank you. However, do you see any reason why the findvertex method would return NULL if the value is really located in map1? I've called the findvertex method elsewhere and printed out an attribute of the returned vertex just fine.

Comment: @AlexAlex There is nothing apparently wrong with your code there. The problem is not the find algorithm. I think it is the inserting in to the map. If you can use some debugger and put a break point in the find algorithm to see what map1 contains when it reaches there you can solve this in about 10 mins. :)